# detect when playback controls are on the screen

Tags: controls, playback, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to display a banner in the lower third an AVPlayer. I am trying to detect when an AVPlayerViewController's playback controls appear and disappear from the screen so I can hide the banner accordingly.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same thing. Just like how the youtube app works.

Comment: Still no luck about this :))